# How to tell Minicom to translate CP437 characters to Unicode equivalents?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, gnu-screen, tty

I am using a Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian [based on debian]) to act as a sort of adapter between **UTF-8/SSH over TCP/IP** and **CP437/TTY over RS232/DB9**. The RS232 side is a black box that we cannot really modify at all.

Initially I was using `screen` as an intermediate which seems to do this CP437 -> Unicode on the fly automatically.  However, this required me to allow the SSH user to initially login to a full shell, then run `screen`, which is too advanced / technical of a process for the intended user.

This is why I am looking at using `minicom` which is perfectly suitable to be used as a login shell.  They can't get to a bash shell, and exiting minicom also closes the SSH session, which is more user friendly for the intended user persona, and does not require a huge effort to lock down user access.

The problem is that `minicom` is not properly converting the CP437 style borders to Unicode, in the same way `screen` does. It instead converts to `lqqqk` borders (PuTTY terminology).

See below for examples:

*This is what `screen` does (looks perfect, uses unicode)*

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│Platform Magnet Supervisory "MGN 07/14/03 V1.0.0 551-373"     │
│                                                              │
├ command ─┬ syntax ─────┬ function ───────────────────────────┤
│ Run      │ R           │ Run process display                 │
│ Time     │ T hh:mm:ss  │ set clock time                      │
│ Date     │ D dd/mm/yy  │ set date                            │
│ Start    │ S hh:mm:ss  │ set start time                      │
└──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

*This is what `minicom` does without any special settings (called `lqqqk` borders by PuTTY)*

```
lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk
xPlatform Magnet Supervisory "MGN 07/14/03 V1.0.0 551-373"     x
x                                                              x
t command qw syntax qqqqqw function qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqu
x Run      x R           x Run process display                 x
x Time     x T hh:mm:ss  x set clock time                      x
x Date     x D dd/mm/yy  x set date                            x
x Start    x S hh:mm:ss  x set start time                      x
mqqqqqqqqqqvqqqqqqqqqqqqqvqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
```

*This is what `minicom` does with a few settings that allow direct pass-through of values*

```
ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄڿ
³Platform Magnet Supervisory "MGN 07/14/03 V1.0.0 551-373"     ³
³                                                              ³
Ã command ÄÂ syntax ÄÄÄÄÄÂ function ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄô
³ Run      ³ R           ³ Run process display                 ³
³ Time     ³ T hh:mm:ss  ³ set clock time                      ³
³ Date     ³ D dd/mm/yy  ³ set date                            ³
³ Start    ³ S hh:mm:ss  ³ set start time                      ³
ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÁÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÁÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
```

The third example is actually somewhat usable with additional steps. I am able to tell the SSH client (PuTTY) to render the terminal using a [CP437-like font](https://cp437.github.io/) and the borders look about 95% correct. However, this is not ideal since the forced font dramatically limits the ability for the user to customize their terminal (or use copy/paste). The end user may also be using an SSH client without font options.

I would much prefer having `minicom` also translate the extended ascii (128-255) characters into the 94XX Unicode characters, similar to how `screen` does. I've read that `ncurses` does this on behalf of `screen`, but `minicom` does its own thing?

I've tried just about every `minicom` configuration without getting it to work. Including `-t` with various TERM values (e.g. `ibmpc`, `linux`, etc).  I've seen a lot of posts where people seem to get it to work with tricks like `export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1`, but I'm just not having the same luck.

Also, I've seen a lot of screenshots where the built-in `minicom` menu is drawn using CP437/ACS borders, but for some reason my version of minicom won't even draw those nicely, and instead uses 'poor mans' borders (PuTTY terminology) rather than [these kinds of borders](https://www.acmesystems.it/www/minicom/minicom_setup.png).

```
+-----[configuration]------+
| Filenames and paths      |
| File transfer protocols  |
| Serial port setup        |
| Modem and dialing        |
| Screen and keyboard      |
| Save setup as dfl        |
| Save setup as..          |
| Exit                     |
| Exit from Minicom        |
+--------------------------+
```

It seems like perhaps something [like this](https://github.com/keaston/cp437) could do the trick, but it would also prevent us from running Minicom as a shell, so I've ruled that out for now.

Really running out of ideas but this seems possible! Any help or tips appreciated!

Comment: What version of PuTTY are you using? The latest versions *do* recognize ACS box drawings even while in UTF-8 mode.

Comment: PuTTY Release 0.74.  If you mean "Enable VT100 line drawings even in UTF-8 mode", I tried that as well without luck.  Though since that's PuTTY specific, it would not be an ideal solution.  I also tried using various 'remote character set' options (like CP437) for PuTTY without luck.